# Is the use of select_related() more efficient when doing a filtered select on the related object field of a set of model objects?

Tags: django, django-models

In the djangoproject docs the following is mentioned:

`Note that the select_related() QuerySet method recursively prepopulates the cache of all one-to-many relationships ahead of time. Example:`

```
>>> e = Entry.objects.select_related().get(id=2)
>>> print(e.blog)  # Doesn't hit the database; uses cached version.
>>> print(e.blog)  # Doesn't hit the database; uses cached version.
```

Is recursively prepopulating the cache ahead of time more efficient then not doing so? And what if Entry had another relation to, say object X, would object X also be cached ahead of time? In other words, would all related object fields Entry may possess be cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's [select_related](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L1013) will fetch all related fields by default, however it takes fields as arguments to change this behaviour. Whether this is 'efficient' is entirely up to the implementation